# Update value of a column using existing column value in Django

Tags: python, django

how to perform following SQL operation using Django object:

```
update table set column = column+x where column>5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [`F()` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for this.

```
Table.objects.filter(column__gt=5).update(column=F('column')+1)
```

Note, it will help you to learn Django if you start thinking in terms of models and fields rather than tables and columns.

Comment: is this answer in terms of models and fields or tables and columns